# How to get the data of the intersection of image and div in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an image inside a div. The image is draggable. I can move it inside or outside the div. Now, I want to get the image data that intersects the div using *jquery*. The data could be the width, height and position of image. Here is my sample code:

```
 <img src="image.jpg" style="position:absolute; z-index:2; 
    top: 0px; left:0px; width: 300px; height: 300px;">
 <div style="width:300px; height: 300px; position: absolute; 
   z-index:1; top: 100px; left: 100px;"></div>
```

Here is the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lhub3c46/1/

Does anybody know?

[image]

Comment: What have you already tried? What do you need to retrieve?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, but I just want to get the image data (red background)  that intersects with the div. @BenM

Comment: Post example with working dragable div and image

Comment: Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/Lhub3c46/1/ @Wimanicesir

Comment: You will probably need to use canvas for that. If you want to get the intersecting area between the div and the image, you need to use `getBoundingClientRect()` to get the coordinates and size of both elements and use math to calculate the intersecting area and its four coordinates, relative to the image element.

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle with some similar behavior. 
**Note** Its very quick and dirty *and you should not take it as granted*.

There needs to be variable management, functionality separated into proper functions, proper variable naming, bug fixing, implementing missing cases, testing, etc etc etc...

However, it could help you by giving you a small rolling start.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7oxrqev/1/)

```
e
```